# ReadyAPI version 3.20.2: An incorrect endpoint is specified

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I've some tests written in ReadyAPI that works just fine in previous versions of ReadyAPI. Downloaded latest version of ReadyAPI yesterday (ReadyAPI 3.20.2 (February 22, 2022)) and got this error when I tried to execute the teststep:

> ERROR: An incorrect endpoint is specified for the request [myRequest]

I can't find any more in logs that can indicate what's wrong. My teststep URL is as follows:

```
${#Project#ServiceEndPoint}/ServicecenterNext/odata/v1/Requests(${#TestCase#Id})
```

Where Project#ServiceEndPoint is set to https://myTestApp.test.com and TestCaseId is already set with Groovy-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit https://community.smartbear.com/t5/ReadyAPI-Questions/ReadyAPI-3-9-2-Deactivate-check-for-incorrect-endpoint/td-p/221790

-Dreadyapi.skip.endpoints.checks=true